# Conditional Access

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

Our signUp page starts with entering a username and validating the username against the directory. In case of a wrong username attempt, we need to track the IP address of a user and after a certain number of the wrong attempt, we need to disallow the user for more attempts for 10 mins.

Comment: Please refer this it may help you : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management

Answer (score 0):

You can lockout the the account for specific time period of time who is trying to login with wrong credentail.

In the left menu, select `Azure AD B2C`. Or, select All services and search for and select `Azure AD B2C`.

Under `Security`, select `Authentication methods (Preview)`, then select `Password protection`.

Under Custom smart lockout, enter your desired smart lockout settings:

***Lockout threshold*** : You can set the a count after that sigin try use account will be lockout..

***Lockout duration in seconds***: For this Specfied period of time user can not login.

***Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/threat-management***

You can track the IP address of user in ***sigin activity logs***.

You can refer this [**MS document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/view-audit-logs)  under ***View audit logs in the Azure portal***